# Cannot use exported classes in webpack configuration

Tags: javascript, webpack

I need to have multiple configurations of `webpack@5`.
I wanted to create `WebpackBuilder` class that will be responsible for creating that webpack configuration.

So I created that file:

```js
export default class WebpackBuilder {
    test() {
        console.log('Test');
    }
}
```

When I import that file using `const WebpackBuilder = require('./webpack.builder');` I got errors:

```
[webpack-cli] C:\strony\www\polskieszlaki_new\strony\webpack.builder.js:3
export default class WebpackBuilder {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

When using `import WebpackBuilder from './webpack.builder';`

```
[webpack-cli] C:\strony\www\polskieszlaki_new\strony\webpack.blog.config.js:2
import WebpackBuilder from './webpack.builder';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

My webpack command is `webpack --mode=production --config webpack.blog.config.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you imported an `esm` module into your configuration file which is written in `cjs` style.

You have to turn your `esm` module to `cjs`:

```js
class WebpackBuilder {
    test() {
        console.log('Test');
    }
}


module.exports = WebpackBuilder;
```

NOTE: You can also find out more languages to write the configuration file here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-languages/